# Importing CSV into R handling new lines

Tags: r, excel, text, data-cleaning

I am importing a CSV database into R, using the following code:

```
CGS  <- read.csv("filepath", sep=";", dec=",", na.strings=c(""," ","NA"), stringsAsFactors =F)
```

However, I noticed that in the original database some cells with string characters they look like this:

[image]

which when I look in the dataframe in R, I see that R puts the "new line" symbol \n in the relevant character vector, looking like this:

```
[13] "Q.12j. Enterprises in a specific sector (other than agriculture or RDI) \n    funding options (e.g. EU funds, venture capital products, loans, guarantees etc.)"
```

After some data manipulations that I do using this dataframe, I export this to a txt file using:

```
write.table(CGS, "df.txt",sep="\t", row.names=FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

However, I discovered because of this \n, the problem that it creates for me is that when I use this text file to import the data in excel, excel reads and puts the data into a new row.

My remedy was to substitute the \n with space, using the following lines of code:

```
CGS$Sub.Question<-gsub("\n", "", CGS$Sub.Question)
```

However, I would like to ask whether there is another solution that I can use in R, which does this for me automatically in the reading step. Is there, for example, an option in read.csv() function that I should be aware of ?

Comment: Side note: When I use `write.csv(data.frame(header=c("my text", "just \"another \ntext\"")), tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"), row.names = F);writeClipboard(tf)` and open it in Excel, everything looks fine.

Comment: Yes, I checked and excel can read csv having new-lines in some records, but you need to quote those records, so set `quote = TRUE` in `write.table`

Comment: Just a question... are you opening the txt file in excel, or just copy-pasting the text into excel ?

Comment: Yes, I am importing the text file in excel. No copy and paste.